# Pivoting table in SQl Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot, currency-exchange-rates

We have CurrencyRatestable as follows:

[image]

We need to arrange this table horizontally as:

```
TransactionCurrency|EUR rate|INR Rate|USD Rate|Effectie Date
GBP                |0.893   |0.0115  |0.7992  |2019-06-18 00:00:00:000
INR                |78.0005 |1       |69.7242 |2019-06-18 00:00:00:000
USD                |1.1187  |0.0143  |1       |2019-06-18 00:00:00:000
EUR                |1       |0.0128  |0.8939  |2019-06-18 00:00:00:000
GBP                |0.8902  |0.0114  |0.7943  |2019-06-19 00:00:00:000
INR                |78.0755 |1       |69.6667 |2019-06-19 00:00:00:000
USD                |1.1207  |0.0144  |1       |2019-06-19 00:00:00:000
EUR                |1       |0.0128  |0.8923  |2019-06-19 00:00:00:000
```

and so on

I have basic knowledge of SQL. Can PIVOT function do this? What should be the starting point of the query? As my trial gave error.

```
select * from (SELECT  
      [BaseCurrency] ,
      [TransactionCurrency], 
      [EffectiveDate],
      [Rate]
  FROM [PDI].[dbo].[Dim_CurrencyRates]
  )cur
  PIVOT(
 
  FOR [BaseCurrency] in ('EUR','INR','USD')
  )As PivTab
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it shows no effort to research PIVOT operator nor even attempt to use it.

Comment: I tried using PIVOT, but there is no aggregate function to apply, so could not proceed further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I often use `max` when I don't need to aggregate.

```
select 
    TransactionCurrency,
    EUR as [EUR rate],
    INR as [INR Rate],
    USD as [USD Rate],
    EffectiveDate
from [PDI].[dbo].[Dim_CurrencyRates]
pivot(
    max(Rate) 
    for BaseCurrency in (EUR, INR, USD)) as pv
```